# How to read the url query parameters in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a simple `angularjs` app and want to read the query parameters of the url `mypath.com/test.html?param1=test`.

Question: how can I read and modify the parameters list?

`$location.search()` does not return any results here.

Comment: so what _does_ `$location.search()` return?

Comment: `[Object object]` that cannot be inspected.

Comment: and what if you `console.log(Object.keys($location.search()))` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must activate the html5Mode before calling : $location.search()

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: Could you add an example how to use the url with `#` when referencing on a `test.html` directly? That sounds promising.